# Dropping rows in Pandas based off multiple empty cells?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, row

So here I have an example dataframe on what I'm trying to accomplish. The three cell values are empty under the headers value1, value2, and value3 that row will drop.

```
import pandas as pd
import xldd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

data = [[‘tom’, 10], [‘nick’], [‘juli’]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [‘Name’, ‘Value1’, ‘Value2’, 
‘Value3’])

df.dropna(subset=[‘value1’, ‘value2’, ‘value3’], 
how=‘all’).head()

df.to_excel(‘ReportList.xlsx’, index=False)
```

There are no errors in this code, but nothing happens when code is ran.

Comment: you need to reassign the dataframe `df = df.dropna(subset=[‘value1’, ‘value2’, ‘value3’], 
how=‘all’)`

Comment: Thanks! That was such a super simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

As @Datanovice mentioned, you need to assign dataframe to new dataframe or use the `inplace` parameter and set it to true.

```
In [138]: data = [['tom', 10,None,None], ['nick',None,None,None], ['juli',None,None,None]]
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Value1', 'Value2',
     ...: 'Value3'])

In [139]: df
Out[139]:
   Name  Value1 Value2 Value3
0   tom    10.0   None   None
1  nick     NaN   None   None
2  juli     NaN   None   None

In [140]: df.dropna(subset=['Value1','Value2','Value3'], how='all',inplace=True)

In [141]: df
Out[141]:
  Name  Value1 Value2 Value3
0  tom    10.0   None   None
```